# Split array into chunk of different size on the basis of their attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this following array

```
var array=[{ semster:1, name:Book1 }, { semster:1, name:Book2 }, { semster:2, name:Book4 }, { semster:3, name:Book5 }, { semster:3, name:Book6 }, { semster:4, name:Book7 }]
```

Now I want to sort my array to split the current array into chunks of array like following

```
var array=[[{ semster:1, name:Book1 }, { semster:1, name:Book2 }],[ { semster:2, name:Book4 }], [{ semster:3, name:Book5 }, { semster:3, name:Book6 }], [{ semster:4, name:Book7 }]]
```

I have tried to achieve this with following code :

```
function splitIntoSubArray(arr, count) {
  var newArray = [];
  while (arr.length > 0) {
    newArray.push(arr.splice(0, count)); 
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

But this can only divide the array on the basis of fixed size. Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is the data always sorted by semester?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes it is

Comment: Do you want to split the array based on each object's values?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have an object where the semester is the key and the value is an array of books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `Array.reduce()` to group items by semester. `Object.values()` on the map gives you the desired result.

```js
var array=[{ semster:1, name:"Book1" }, { semster:1, name:"Book2" }, { semster:2, name:"Book4" }, { semster:3, name:"Book5" }, { semster:3, name:"Book6" }, { semster:4, name:"Book7" }];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, curr)=>{
  (a[curr.semster] = a[curr.semster] || []).push(curr);
  return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by checking the last group with the same semester.

```js
var array = [{ semester: 1, name: 'Book1' }, { semester: 1, name: 'Book2' }, { semester: 2, name: 'Book4' }, { semester: 3, name: 'Book5' }, { semester: 3, name: 'Book6' }, { semester: 4, name: 'Book7' }],
    grouped = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (last && last[0].semester === o.semester) {
            last.push(o);
        } else {
            r.push([o]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```